# jquery graph to repersent time and temperature

Tags: jquery, jqplot

[image]i have used high charts to draw a graph based on time and temperature
[http://www.highcharts.com/]. I have used the code some thisng like this [http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/8263/] but not able to achive the time VS Temprature out put

Do any one know a jquery graph which represent the time Vs temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/). It is a pure JavaScript plotting library for jQuery.

Comment: hi sgun , thanks for the reply its good ...